# Installing Restund on AWS EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, tls, ec2

I have successfully installed Restund on a Vagrant Machine running Ubuntu.  But when I tried to install it on AWS EC2 Instance running Ubuntu, I get an error when starting Restund.

```
Error Message: tls not supported
```

If I disable tls in the /etc/restund.conf file, the message goes away and restund starts up working as intended.  But without secure support. And I am trying to make sure I am communicating with my turn server securely.

My /etc/restund.conf has the following:

```
tls_listen              MY_IP_ADDRESS:3479,/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil-cert-and-key.pem
```

I'm using a fake cert for development purposes and testing before I am ready to go live with a real domain, etc.

I created the cert with the following:

```
make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil
cat /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem >> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil-cert-and-key.pem
cat /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key >> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil-cert-and-key.pem
```

Restund is a stun/turn [server](http://www.creytiv.com/restund.html).

I'm not sure how to enable the TLS Support that Restund needs.

Thanks in advance for any help you might offer!

Comment: This would likely be a better question for the restund support community (e.g. mailing lists) than for U&L.

Comment: HalosGhost, I just wanted to say thank you for cleaning up the post. I hadn't realized there was an option to make it look like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem was to do the following:

1. Install libssl-dev
2. Recompile Libre (a restund dependency) and reinstall
3. Recompile restund and reinstall.

That fixed it!

Thanks to Richard Aas at the re-devel mailing list for the answer.